# Is "relinquishing" an object different than throwing it?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, equipment, incorporeal

According to [Realms Help](http://www.realmshelps.net/monsters/subtype.shtml)

> An object that the creature relinquishes loses its incorporeal quality.

So if a ghost has a sword and puts it down, even if it was not physically present before, it pops into existence in the prime material plane. What if it it is thrown instead?

Comment: Are you asking what it means (title), or are you asking what happens to different kinds of objects a ghost might put down (body)?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie What it means (title). Relinquishing control is different somehow than throwing/ launching it (as in an arrow), I THINK. But maybe I'm wrong

Comment: That's yet a different question from what it seemed the title or body was asking. I've updated the post to reflect the comments and be one question.

Answer (score 8):

**If** you are using [Realms Help](http://www.realmshelps.net/monsters/subtype.shtml) as your source of rules, then it says the following:

> Any equipment worn or carried by an incorporeal creature is also incorporeal as long as it remains in the creature's possession. An object that the creature relinquishes loses its incorporeal quality (and the creature loses the ability to manipulate the object). **If an incorporeal creature uses a thrown weapon or a ranged weapon, the projectile becomes corporeal as soon as it is fired** and can affect a corporeal target normally (no miss chance).

There is little difference between throwing a thrown weapon, and dropping an item, so the item would become corporeal.

---

**However,** the [D20 SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#incorporealSubtype) (which is far more official and recognised) *makes no mention of items becoming corporeal at all.*